# tableview not loading data correctly in cells Swift

Tags: swift, null, swift2, tableview, uitableview

I am making an app that pushes data from RecipiesViewController to TableViewController2. The cells in TableViewController2 use the TableViewCell2 class. For some reason the cells aren't loading correctly and instead of displaying the information that I am entering, they are just showing up blank. I've been trying to find the error for a while now but for some odd reason everything I try is just coming up with the same problem. This is my TableViewController2 class:

```
import UIKit

struct Recipe2 {
let name: String
let thumbnails: String
let description: String
}

class TableViewController2: UITableViewController {

var firstRecipe: Recipe?
var recipies2 = [Recipe2]()
let identifier: String = "Cell2"

var checked = [Bool]()
var toPass:String!
var lightPressed:String!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title =  (firstRecipe?.name)! + " Instruments"
    initializeTherecipies2()



    //            InstrumentTableCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return recipies2.count
}



func initializeTherecipies2()
{
    if (firstRecipe?.name)! == "Disinfectant"
    {
            self.recipies2 = [Recipe2(name: "Instrument", thumbnails: "", description: ""),
                             Recipe2(name: "AMI Codes-II", thumbnails: "AMI Codes II.jpg", description: "A-25.441.100.0"),
                             Recipe2(name: "Optional addon", thumbnails: "", description: ""),
                             Recipe2(name: "Reagent Set DPD", thumbnails: "", description: "A-85.410.120"),
                             Recipe2(name: "pH&T Option Codes", thumbnails: "", description: "A-87.127.020"),
                             Recipe2(name: "pH Cal set", thumbnails: "", description: "A-85.119.010"),
                             Recipe2(name: "manual", thumbnails: "", description: "A‐96.250.571"),
                             Recipe2(name: "Instrument", thumbnails: "", description: ""),
                             Recipe2(name: "AMI Codes-II TC", thumbnails: "AMI Codes II CC.jpg", description: "A-25.441.700.0"),
                             Recipe2(name: "Optional addon", thumbnails: "", description: ""),
                             Recipe2(name: "Reagent set, DPD", thumbnails: "", description: " A-85.410.120"),
                             Recipe2(name: "Reagent set, KI", thumbnails: "", description: "A-85.419.200"),
                             Recipe2(name: "pH&T Option Codes", thumbnails: "", description: "A-87.127.020"),
                             Recipe2(name: "pH Cal set", thumbnails: "", description: "A-85.119.010"),
                             Recipe2(name: "manual", thumbnails: "", description: "A‐96.250.631"),
                             Recipe2(name: "Instrument", thumbnails: "", description: ""),
                             Recipe2(name: "AMI Codes-II CC", thumbnails: "AMI Codes II TC.jpg", description: "A-25.441.600.0"),
                             Recipe2(name: "Optional addon", thumbnails: "", description: ""),
                             Recipe2(name: "Reagent set, DPD", thumbnails: "", description: "A-85.410.120"),
                             Recipe2(name: "Reagent set, KI", thumbnails: "", description: "A-85.419.200"),
                             Recipe2(name: "pH&T Option Codes", thumbnails: "", description: "A-87.127.020"),
                             Recipe2(name: "pH Cal set", thumbnails: "", description: "A-85.119.010"),
                             Recipe2(name: "manual", thumbnails: "", description: "A‐96.250.581")]



            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    else if (firstRecipe?.name)! == "Oxygen"
    {
        self.recipies2 = [Recipe2(name: "Chlorine", thumbnails: "Chlorine.jpg", description: "Description"),
                         Recipe2(name: "Water", thumbnails: "water.jpg", description: "Description"),
                         Recipe2(name: "Oxygen", thumbnails: "Oxygen.png", description: "Description"),
                         Recipe2(name: "Swan", thumbnails: "Swan.gif", description: "Description"),
                         Recipe2(name: "Element", thumbnails: "PerioticTable.jpg", description: "Description"),
                         Recipe2(name: "H2O", thumbnails: "H2O.png", description: "Description"),
                         Recipe2(name: "Starbucks Coffee", thumbnails: "starbucks_coffee.jpg", description: "Description")]

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    else if (firstRecipe?.name)! == "Conductivity"
    {
        self.recipies2 = [Recipe2(name: "[[[AMI Turbiwell]]]", thumbnails: "AMITurbiwell.jpg", description: "A-209.123"),
                         Recipe2(name: "[[[Swansensor]]]", thumbnails: "Swansensor.jpg", description: "A-720.020")]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else if (firstRecipe?.name)! == "ISE"
    {
        self.recipies2 = [Recipe2(name: "AMI Turbiwell", thumbnails: "AMITurbiwell.jpg", description: "A-209.123"),
                         Recipe2(name: "Swansensor", thumbnails: "Swansensor.jpg", description: "A-720.020")]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else if (firstRecipe?.name)! == "Phosphate"
    {
        self.recipies2 = [Recipe2(name: "AMI Turbiwell", thumbnails: "AMITurbiwell.jpg", description: "A-209.123"),
                         Recipe2(name: "Swansensor", thumbnails: "Swansensor.jpg", description: "A-720.020")]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else if (firstRecipe?.name)! == "SAC254"
    {
        self.recipies2 = [Recipe2(name: "AMI Turbiwell", thumbnails: "AMITurbiwell.jpg", description: "A-209.123"),
                         Recipe2(name: "Swansensor", thumbnails: "Swansensor.jpg", description: "A-720.020")]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else if (firstRecipe?.name)! == "Turbidity"
    {
        self.recipies2 = [Recipe2(name: "AMI Turbiwell", thumbnails: "AMITurbiwell.jpg", description: "A-209.123"),
                         Recipe2(name: "Swansensor", thumbnails: "Swansensor.jpg", description: "A-720.020")]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else if (firstRecipe?.name)! == "pH/ORP"
    {
        self.recipies2 = [Recipe2(name: "AMI Turbiwell", thumbnails: "AMITurbiwell.jpg", description: "A-209.123"),
                         Recipe2(name: "Swansensor", thumbnails: "Swansensor.jpg", description: "A-720.020")]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }



}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                        heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("instrumentTableCell") as! InstrumentTableCell!

    if indexPath.row == 1 {//should be if cell.backgroundcolor or something
        return 50//noncolored cells
    } else {
        return 50 // colored cells
    }
}
// MARK: - UITableView DataSource

//        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//            return recipies2.count
//        }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell2"
    let cell: TableViewCell2! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? TableViewCell2

    checked = Array(count:recipies2.count, repeatedValue:false)
   // cell.configurateTheCell(recipies2[indexPath.row])

    if !checked[indexPath.row] {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    } else if checked[indexPath.row] {
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }


    return cell
}

//    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
//        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
//            recipes.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
//            self.tableView?.reloadData()
//            self.tableView?.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)
//        }
//    }

//MARK: - UITableView Delegate
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
            checked[indexPath.row] = false
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            checked[indexPath.row] = true
        }
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segue2") {
        let seg = segue.destinationViewController as! thirdTableViewController
        var arr: [Recipe2] = [Recipe2]()
        for index in 0..<recipies2.count {
            if checked[index] {
                arr.append(self.recipies2[index])
            }
        }
        seg.catagory = toPass
        seg.selectedRecipes = arr
    }

}
}
```

and this is my TableViewCell2 class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var descriptionLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet var thumbnailImage: UIImageView!

func configurateTheCell(recipie: Recipe2) {
    self.nameLabel?.text = recipie.name
    self.descriptionLabel?.text = recipie.description
    self.thumbnailImage?.image = UIImage(named: recipie.thumbnails)
    if nameLabel!.text == "Instrument"
    {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        nameLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        userInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    else if nameLabel!.text == "Optional addon"
    {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
        nameLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        userInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    else
    {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        nameLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

}

}
```

Comment: have you checked if tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is returning nil or not?

Comment: First of all I don't see your RecipesViewController where you said you send information to your `TableViewController2 `. I don't know why the method `initializeTherecipies2 ` exist, you should pass this information to the `TableViewController2` not have it hardcoded inside it.

Comment: `configuateTheCell` is commented out, is this not where the cells are setup?

Comment: @Luke thanks that worked!

Comment: @Luke im not sure why I commented that out, I couldn't fix it for so long XD

Comment: Dude, I recommend you be little bit careful with architecture of your project. View is filling by itself, that's very very bad practice.